# Possible to send data to external source (such as a form) on button click in Salesforce?

Tags: lightning-aura-components, lightning-experience

I have a lightning component (button), and on click I would like to send current data about the object to the page that is opening to pre-populate a form so the data does not have to be entered numerous times. Is this at all possible?

Comment: Where do you have this lightning button?

Comment: On a standard object page.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess you want to have a forwarding to a "real" webpage (outside of Salesforce) - if so you can dispatch a [navigateToURL](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.lightning.meta/lightning/ref_force_navigateToURL.htm) event and use URL parameters populated with your data. The other page must take care about GET-Parameters.
Have a look at the examples given on the provided link.

Comment: I figured this would be the only way, but at least it's possible. Thanks.